# Mutate previous data in setQueryData

Tags: reactjs, react-query

In react-query, [`setQueryData`](https://react-query.tanstack.com/reference/QueryClient#queryclientsetquerydata) has an overload which accepts an update function as such

```
setQueryData('myQuery', oldData => newData);
```

In this function is it ok to mutate the state of oldData and return it?
For example

```
setQueryData('myQuery', oldData => {
    oldData.foo = 42;
    return oldData
}
```

Or is `oldData` immutable and must be modified with rest/spread operators or e.g. `immer`?

The [examples](https://react-query.tanstack.com/guides/updates-from-mutation-responses) [all](https://react-query.tanstack.com/examples/optimistic-updates) show returning a new instance, but documentation does not explicitly say one way or the other.

Mutating in place seems to work but I'm not sure if there are any pitfalls. I know with e.g. `setState` I would have to return a new value.

*Why not return a new instance just in case?* The query data is very big and I only need to modify a single field.

### Update

Looking at the source code of [query::setData](https://github.com/tannerlinsley/react-query/blob/master/src/core/query.ts) which is what `setQueryData` calls, as far as I can tell the observers of the query will be notified via a call to `dispatch` in all cases where `setQueryData` is called; I don't see an early-out when `oldData` is reference-equal to `newData`. Given this, are there any risks?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

mutating is discouraged and should not be used. The problem is that while it looks like it might work on first sight because the cached value does get changed, the reference stays the same, so react-query will *not* inform observers of the change.

As with most data structures in react, it is better to work immutably.

Comment: Thanks for answering. However looking at the source code of query.ts (see update to question) indicates that the observers will be notified on every call of `setQueryData`, there is no early out based on reference equality. Do you disagree? Am I reading it wrong?

Comment: we've made some changes around that area in v4, but even there, the simple case seems to work. However, a bail out currently is done when combined with the select option. I made a codesandbox here: https://codesandbox.io/s/setquerydata-ui3tvl?file=/src/App.tsx bottom line is: I wouldn't rely on it, we might add more bail-out capabilities on terms of referential equality in the future.

Comment: thanks for making that. Interesting that in your sandbox mutating doesn't work even if I remove the `select:` option. The data gets changed in the query but a rerender is not triggered.

Comment: I see now. this must have changed in v4. If I set the version to 3.38.0 then mutating works. In the interest of future proofing I should just return a new instance. Thank you.

Comment: I think this is because of tracked queries being the default in v4. We only trigger re-renders for properties that have changed _and_ are used by the component in question. I think _dataUpdatedAt_ or so does change, but since you're not consuming it, there is no re-render. v3 had this optimization opt-in, now you can opt out via `notifyOnChangeProps: "all"`. But yeah, work immutably and you don't have to worry :)